# deepcopy class without __init__()

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, deep-copy, python-class

I've faced an issue when tried to write a module for adding options to different classes. Here is the code:

```py
import copy
from itertools import chain

from future.utils import with_metaclass, iteritems


class Option(object):
        def __init__(self, val):
                self.__set__("", val)

        def __set__(self, instance, value):
                self.value = value

        def __get__(self, instance, owner):
                return self.value


class OptionsAggregator(type):
        def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
                try:
                        external_attrs = chain([base.external for base in bases])
                except AttributeError:
                        attrs['external'] = {}
                else:
                        attrs['external'] = {k: v for d in external_attrs for k, v in iteritems(d)}

                for key, value in iteritems(attrs.copy()):
                        if isinstance(value, Option):
                                attrs['external'].update({key.lower(): value.value})

                return super(OptionsAggregator, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class Options(with_metaclass(OptionsAggregator, object)):
        pass

class A(Options):
        var1 = Option("sas")

        def acheck(self):
                print(self.var1)

class C(A):
        def __init__(self):
                super().__init__()

        def check(self):
                print(self.external)

c = C()

v = copy.deepcopy(c)
v.var1 = 1

n = copy.deepcopy(c)
n.var1 = 4

v.acheck()
n.acheck()
```

The result I am expecting is:

```
1
4
```

But even after copying class the result is:

```
4
4
```

How can I copy `C` class so for each copy there is new `A` with new `var1`. If it is possible, I want class `A` stay the same.

Moreover, I can't move `var1` into `__init__` because if I do this, then `OptionsAggregator` won't be able to see this attribute (in `attrs`) and won't add it to `self.external`.

So, generally my question is: How to deepcopy class if its attribute is not under `__init__` function.

Thanks in advance.